# Cannot open two weblogic console in the same time

Tags: concurrency, weblogic

I have setup two weblogic server version (12.1.3 and 12.2.1.3) in same host.
192.168.0.10:7001 and 192.168.0.10:7003.
I find that if I login one host and operate, I cannot login or operate in another host in the same client computer. It will redirect to login page. Is it normal? Would it affect the operation after production if accessing web applications?

Answer (score 3):

Both domains use the same cookie name set by default for the admin console. Set a different cookie name for the second domain. Use the console and go to Domain -> Configuration -> General -> Advanced Settings and update the property "Console Cookie Name"

Answer (score 0):

It because of the Console Cookie Name which is set in the browser.
We can resolve this issue if we change “Console Cookie Name” at Domain’s configuration advanced settings.

By default, domain’s Console cookie name set to “ADMINCONSOLESESSION”.

You can change the console cookie name for Admin Console by 
Navigating

Click on Domain Name ==>Advanced ==> You will find the Console Cookie Name: parameter just change the parameter in one of the domain .

If you have more than 2 domain running on same machine .Change the Console Cookie Name different So that they don't conflict.

You can check the Console Cookie Name: set by the Admin Console by double clicking the address bar and then click on show cookie and site data and then click on  host name .

Change the Console Cookie Name and then Restart the servers and then We will be able to open multiple Admin Console in the same Browser without any issue .